# Is this return time in micro sec?

Tags: c

```
struct timeval start, end;    
.
.
.
elapsedTime = (((end.tv_sec * 1000000) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000)) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));
```

I just want to double check this returns time in micro sec..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, but watch out for overflow. It's slightly safer to do

```
(end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000
```

then add in the `usec` difference.

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing about overflow.. i was forgetting about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me. I assume you actually initialize the `timeval` to something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does... you are multipling seconds with 1000000 (usec in seconds) and adding usec. Should work